# Finding polygons that contain polygons, with shared edges

Tags: postgis

In PostGIS, how can it be determined if a polygon lies within another *even if* it shares an edge?

`ST_Contains` works well enough, except if there is a shared edge.

---

At the suggestion of @ziggy's comment, I tried to use a "small negative buffer", but to no avail -- either my code is wrong or the operation is inpracticaly slow:

```
SELECT z.id, z.name 
FROM z 
INNER JOIN d ON ST_Contains( 
    z.geom, 
    ST_Buffer( d.geom, -1)
)
WHERE d.id = '933';
```

The best I can come up with is to check just the centroid:

```
SELECT z.id, z.name 
FROM z 
INNER JOIN d ON ST_Contains( 
    z.geom, 
     ST_Centroid(d.geom)
)
WHERE d.id = '933';
```

But that doesn't work for polygons shaped like a letter C....

Comment: you can do a small negative buffer then use st_contains or st_within

Comment: `ST_Contains` does work for nested polygons with shared edges.  Can you post the data for the geometries which don't work?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: It's not too difficult to set up topology in postgis.  This would clean up your edges that don't match up exactly, allowing you to run st_contains and get the expected result.  Here's the docs https://postgis.net/docs/Topology.html.  And this post has a function for loading topology 1 feature at a time to catch errors http://blog.mathieu-leplatre.info/use-postgis-topologies-to-clean-up-road-networks.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If area of intersection of two polygons A and B is equqal to area of polygon B, then B lies within A. However, I think it's not the fastest metod and it doesn't work for degenerate polygons.

```
SELECT z.id, z.name 
FROM z 
INNER JOIN d ON ST_Intersects(z.geom, d.geom) 
    and ST_Area(ST_Intersection(z.geom, d.geom)) = ST_Area(z.geom)
    and ST_Area(z.geom) > 0;
```